# Ubuntu 12.10 being unable to mount Windows drives

Tags: windows

Ubuntu 12.10 doesn't show the one of my windows drives. When I try to mount the drive, ubuntu shows:

```
ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Failed to read $MFTMirr: Input/output error
Failed to mount '/dev/sda6': Input/output error
NTFS is inconsistent.
```

One more problem is also there: When I try to install Windows 7 with live dvd as well as USB, the installation freezes at the screen 'Setup is Starting...'.

Please help me in this issue because there are various important files in that drive.....

Comment: is the partition a windows primary partition where the actual OS is installed ? If yes then please mention what WINDOWS version is installed.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem in the past, where Ubuntu didn't mount a Windows drive. What I did was start Windows, open partition manager and slightly resize the Ubuntu partition, then went back to Ubuntu and open the drive! Tada! It works!

Let me know if this works out for you, because there is no real computering behind this.

Thanks, mjchopperboy

Answer (score 1):

Download `ntfsprogs` package

> sudo apt-get install ntfsprogs

then fix the partition by running

> sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda6